# ob_gzhandler returns wrong result

Tags: php

I'm testing my site where i use ob_gzhandler to compress output and got an interesting error. According to docs "If a browser doesn't support compressed pages this function returns FALSE".
Here is my test code:

```
<?php
$res = ob_start( 'ob_gzhandler' ) ;
echo 'My text' ;
var_dump( $res ) ;
```

I'm using ff5.0 and if i don't change any headers all works fine, here is the listing:
Live HTTP Headers ouput

```
http://tester.loc/ob-test/gz.php

GET /ob-test/gz.php HTTP/1.1
Host: tester.loc
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://tester.loc/ob-test/
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 10:37:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1  mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 126
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Script output:

```
My text
boolean true
```

But when i remove Accept-Encoding header, ob_gzhandler still returns true. Listing again:
Live HTTP Headers ouput

```
http://tester.loc/ob-test/gz.php

GET /ob-test/gz.php HTTP/1.1
Host: tester.loc
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://tester.loc/ob-test/
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 10:35:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1
Content-Length: 109
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Script output

```
My text
boolean true
```

So in both cases ob_gzhandler returns true though it supposed to be false in the second sample. Is it my misunderstanding or a bug?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the

```
ob_gzhandler()
```

function itself which will return false, this isn't what you are calling (directly).

ob_start() only returns false if the callback fails, I don't think that ob_gzhandler() returning false is the same as it failing.

Comment: Nope, i guess it's not the issue. In addition docs says "This function was changed to return FALSE in case the passed output_callback can not be executed." (in ob_start article) And ob_gzhandler requires 2 params in any way, which are supplied by ob_start, so i can't run it by itself

Comment: Doh! Sorry. On the doc issue: I think the doc means it'll return false if the callback can't be run rather than it'll return false if the callback itself returns false (which isn't an error as such).

Comment: Yeah, now i tested it and you're right. Just sample codes from doc's comments like [quote]<?php
if(!ob_start('ob_gzhandler')) ob_start();
?>
ob_start('ob_gzhandler') returns FALSE if browser doesn't support gzip, so then is called normal ob_start();[/quote] brought me to wrong conclusions (no wonder, the comment seems to be actually wrong). Thanks in any way.